# Cesium paint the surface of the earth within an AxisAligned bounding box defined in Cartesian3 space

Tags: glsl, cesiumjs

Using Cesium I want to mark the region on the surface that is within a bounding box. I startbed by drawing the bounding box using a BoxGraphics however while you specify the location in Carterisian space it is automatically converted to a box rotated and sized within Lat/Lon space. I used Polyline to draw, though the latest version must be used to support the ArcType, to prevent artificially curved lines.

However both of these draw a box, which is not well occluded by the earth itself and can be hard to tell where it intersects with the surface.

I then started looking at created a fragement shader to be used on the viewer.scene.globe.material that would use a different color if inside the bounding box vs outside based on world position. This was done with a source shader instead of a component shader as more control was needed

However the shaders function czm_material czm_getMaterial(czm_materialInput materialInput) doesnt have access to world coordinates

First I tried "varying vec4 worldCoord" but I think this might be for vertex shader as that failed.

Then I tried "in vec4 fl_FragCoord;" but I get an error " 'in' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only"

Perhaps I am taking the wrong approach using a shader in this case? Perhaps there is a better way to get world position int toe source of the fragement shader?

Not really sure where to go from here to color the surface of the earth in my ECEF AxisAligned Bounding Box